# Compare Two String Variables, Do Something If They Are The Same

Tags: python, string, variables, python-imaging-library, rgb

I am looking to compare two string variables in Python and print `same` if they are the same. Unfortunately I can not get this to work, `same` never get's printed. One of my strings is just a simple variable, while the other is an RGB output from the `ImageGrab` module.

Here is the code:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
import threading

cc = "(255, 255, 255)"

def getcol():
    global pxcolor
    threading.Timer(0.5, getcol).start()
    pixel=ImageGrab.grab((960,540,961,541)).load()
    for y in range(0,1,1):
        for x in range(0,1,1):
            pxcolor=pixel[x,y]
            print(pxcolor)
            if pxcolor == cc:
                print("same")

getcol()
```

I have tried using `pxcolor = pxcolor.strip()` but this returned this error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mikur\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\mikur\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 1158, in run
    self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mikur\Desktop\tye.py", line 14, in getcol
    pxcolor = pxcolor.strip()
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with this library, but are you sure pxcolor is a string? Could you check with `type(pxcolor)`? It looks like it's probably a tuple.

Comment: *pxcolor* is a *tuple* (the error message is pretty clear). Your comparison will never evaluate to *True*. Try `cc = (255, 255, 255)` (declare it as a *tuple*, **not** a *string*). Or the (lame) other way around: `if str(pxcolor) == cc:`

Comment: Yep, sorry for the rookie mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just need to convert the pxcolor to a string via str() to compare them

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
import threading

cc = "(45, 42, 46)"

def getcol():
    global pxcolor
    threading.Timer(0.5, getcol).start()
    pixel=ImageGrab.grab((960,540,961,541)).load()
    for y in range(0,1,1):
        for x in range(0,1,1):
            pxcolor=str(pixel[x,y])
            print(pxcolor)
            if pxcolor == cc:
                print("same")

getcol()
```

As per Kevin's suggestion to make the cc variable a tuple at the start

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
import threading

cc = (45, 42, 46)

def getcol():
    global pxcolor
    threading.Timer(0.5, getcol).start()
    pixel=ImageGrab.grab((960,540,961,541)).load()
    for y in range(0,1,1):
        for x in range(0,1,1):
            pxcolor=pixel[x,y]
            print(pxcolor)
            if pxcolor == cc:
                print("same")

getcol()
```

Comment: It would be better to have `cc` be the same type as `pxcolor` in the first place, rather than convert `pxcolor` to match the type of `cc`. The type of an object should reflect its purpose; a tuple is closer to a color than a string is.

Answer (score 0):

cc is a str, while pxcolor is a tuple

You either need to change cc to a tuple, or pxcolor to a string, and then check the `==` statement:

**The tuple to string**

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
import threading

cc = "(255, 255, 255)"

def getcol():
    global pxcolor
    threading.Timer(0.5, getcol).start()
    pixel=ImageGrab.grab((960,540,961,541)).load()
    for y in range(0,1,1):
        for x in range(0,1,1):
            pxcolor=pixel[x,y]
            print(pxcolor)
            if str(pxcolor) == cc:
                print("same")
```

**The string to tuple**

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
import threading


cc = "(255, 255, 255)"

def getcol():
    global pxcolor
    threading.Timer(0.5, getcol).start()
    pixel=ImageGrab.grab((960,540,961,541)).load()
    for y in range(0,1,1):
        for x in range(0,1,1):
            pxcolor=pixel[x,y]
            print(pxcolor)

            elements = cc[1:-1].split(",")
            tuple_cc = [ int(x) for x in elements ]
            mytuple = tuple(tuple_cc) 

            if pxcolor == mytuple:
                print("same")
```

Comment: I like the idea of changing cc to a tuple. But wouldn't it be easier to simply do `cc = (255, 255, 255)` in the first place rather than call `split` and `tuple()` at runtime?

Comment: yes. good call @Kevin. Obviously if you can have cc as a tuple straight away, that would be ideal. But I don't know what Mihkel has as cc that he's reading in. so was just offering the 2 ways to make his code work with cc being a string